# Angular using $scope

Tags: angularjs, scope

I need get scope to use some specific method.

Is it correct use this code on prod:

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('elementId')).scope()
```

to get some specific scope?

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work?

Comment: No I think, that if you need to use functions on different scope, you should define those functions in a `service`

Comment: `angular.element(..).scope()` will fail if you turn off debug info (which you should be doing in production, as it gives a sizable performance boost). You definitely should not use that method in production code!

Answer (score 0):

did you disable the debug somewhere in your app?
like so

```
$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false)
```

if yes, enable it.

From the Angular doc:

*"Call this method to enable/disable various debug runtime information in the compiler such as adding binding information and a reference to the current scope on to DOM elements."*

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider

Comment: It works in my code as well, but I think forward if it's bad solution